# how to pass grid to "void my_func(void *args)"

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm using `pthread_create()` to call function whose header line is `void * my_func(void *args)`. This function typecasts all the arguments it needs from a data struct.

However, `my_func()` also needs access to a grid that is being created elsewhere.

I've tried passing the grid as an input argument alongside `void *args`, however that results in errors being thrown by function `pthread_create()`, as it doesn't allow/expect this.

I tried instead adding the grid to the struct (not sure if that's a legal move), however that resulted in the grid being 'undeclared' within `my_func()` regardless.

`pthreads_create()` code:

```
     for (k = 0; k < num_threads; k++)
        pthread_create (&thread_id[k], &attributes, my_func, (void *) &thread_data[k]);
```

`my_func()` code:

```
/* This function is executed by each thread to compute the overall Gauss-Seidel. */
void *
my_func (void *args)
{

/* Typecast the argument to a pointer to the thread_data_t structure. */
    thread_data_t *thread_data = (thread_data_t *) args;        

  // int num_iter = 0;
    int done = 0;
    int i, j;
    double diff;
    float old, new; 
    float eps = 1e-2; /* Convergence criteria. */
    int num_elements; 

    int num_iter = 0;

  if (thread_data->tid < (thread_data->num_threads - 1)) {
    for (int k = thread_data->offset; k < (thread_data->offset + thread_data->chunk_size); k++)
        while(!done) { /* While we have not converged yet. */
            diff = 0.0;
            num_elements = 0;

            for (i = 1; i < (grid->dim - 1); i++) {
                for (j = 1; j < (grid->dim - 1); j++) {
                    old = grid->element[i * grid->dim + j]; /* Store old value of grid point. */
                    /* Apply the update rule. */    
                    new = 0.25 * (grid->element[(i - 1) * grid->dim + j] +\
                                  grid->element[(i + 1) * grid->dim + j] +\
                                  grid->element[i * grid->dim + (j + 1)] +\
                                  grid->element[i * grid->dim + (j - 1)]);

                    grid->element[i * grid->dim + j] = new; /* Update the grid-point value. */
                    diff = diff + fabs(new - old); /* Calculate the difference in values. */
                    num_elements++;
                }
            }

            /* End of an iteration. Check for convergence. */
            diff = diff/num_elements;
            printf ("Iteration %d. DIFF: %f.\n", num_iter, diff);
            num_iter++;

            if (diff < eps) 
                done = 1;
            } // end while
  } //end if

  else { /* This takes care of the number of elements that the final thread must process. */  
     int done2 = 0;
    for (int k = thread_data->offset; k < thread_data->dim; k++)         
      while(!done2) { /* While we have not converged yet. */
            diff = 0.0;
            num_elements = 0;

            for (i = 1; i < (grid->dim - 1); i++) {
                for (j = 1; j < (grid->dim - 1); j++) {
                    old = grid->element[i * grid->dim + j]; /* Store old value of grid point. */
                    /* Apply the update rule. */    
                    new = 0.25 * (grid->element[(i - 1) * grid->dim + j] +\
                                  grid->element[(i + 1) * grid->dim + j] +\
                                  grid->element[i * grid->dim + (j + 1)] +\
                                  grid->element[i * grid->dim + (j - 1)]);

                    grid->element[i * grid->dim + j] = new; /* Update the grid-point value. */
                    diff = diff + fabs(new - old); /* Calculate the difference in values. */
                    num_elements++;
                }
            }

            /* End of an iteration. Check for convergence. */
            diff = diff/num_elements;
            printf ("Iteration %d. DIFF: %f.\n", num_iter, diff);
            num_iter++;
                  if (diff < eps) 
                done = 1;

        } // end while
  }// end else    

    /* Store num_iter into the num_iter array. */
    thread_data->num_iter[thread_data->tid] = num_iter;    

    pthread_exit (NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a header file (call it `thread_func.h` or whatever you'd prefer)

```c
#ifndef THREAD_FUNC_H
#define THREAD_FUNC_H
void* my_func(void *args);
#endif
```

Do the same for your `thread_data_s` struct, but in a different header file, and include the definition for it as well.

Create a `.c` file called `thread_func.c`, and put the definition for `my_func(struct thread_data_s *data)` there. Make sure to `#include` the header where you've defined your struct, but do NOT `#include "thread_func.h"` except in your `main.c`. I'd also strongly advise you against casting your pointers.

If you'd like to see an example of the layout I've described, I have one [on my GitHub](https://github.com/PierceGriffiths/Producer-Consumer/tree/master/src).

**Edit:**
As for passing the grid to `my_func`, just make it part of `thread_data_s`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I wound up structuring the code and associated files in this fashion. The Github example helped out as well. cheers.!